# Assembly 32 bit left shifter

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

I am having some trouble getting this procedure called DoLeftShift to work properly. The Shifter procedure is working, I know because I have test values and they all work, so the problem is in DoLeftShift.

For the shifter disabled, I am getting all 0's or all 1's, where it should be the same binary that was put in originally. Enable Shift and Shift Instruction also are not working.

Edit: Code removed because it was part of a homework assignment.

Comment: Don't vandalize your questions by removing the code.  It removes the context for the answer.  (If you have some reason for needing to remove some/all of the code, at least say so in the edit message or people are just going to roll it back.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> mov ecx, $parm2         ;ecx = enable/disable bit
> call Shifter            ;call Shifter procedure
> ```

When you call the *Shifter* procedure, the enable/disable is set just fine (coming from $parm2).

But when you repeatedly call the *Shifter* procedure from within the *loopTop* loop, the `ECX` register no longer holds the correct info!

The *Shifter* procedure never preserves any registers and so the `CL` register is returned in a toggled state (`xor cl, 1   ;cl = NOT cl`).

### Solution:

- Reload the `ECX` from $parm2 each time before calling *Shifter*
- Reverse the toggle of `CL` preferrably at the end of the *Shifter* procedure.
- Preserve any registers that do not return a value.

Comment: Third (and best IMHO)  option: push bl and cl onto the stack at the start of the shifter proc and pop them just before returning.

Comment: @Jeremy: that would be option 3.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Option 3 was added to the answer after I posted my comment, perhaps *because* I posted my comment.

Comment: @JeremyP: very well possible. So you can delete the comment. <g>

Comment: Thanks so much, that was it. I wasn't pushing and popping ebx and ecx in the Shifter procedure before.